# Div wont wrap, but does sometimes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Banging my head against the wall with this one. When "`@media (max-width: 320px)`" the thumbnail  reduces in size leaving space for the div below to float to the right next to it. For some reason it won't work, but on occasions when playing with chrome's "inspect element" and turning on/off the attributes it suddenly works. Working with twitter-bootstrap, here is a bootply http://bootply.com/73043

```
@media ( max-width: 320px ) {
    .thumbnail > a > img {
        width: 40%;
    }
    .pleasewrap {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The button and price is fine where it is, the header and the place needs to float next to the image. Sometimes it does but most of the time it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at it, I think it's related to how the media query rule for the 'pleasewrap' class isn't being picked up by the browser. When its de-activated and re-activated in the Chrome inspector, it picks it up, and does what you want.

Try applying the 'inline-block' display rule at a higher, more general (or the highest, non-media specific), level in your template stylesheet and that should do the job!

Answer (score 0):

http://bootply.com/73044

i've added the clearfix class to the thumbnail div, and some margin/padding for the thumb

Comment: Hi. Yes I tried this, it still does not work. If you move the browser width to and from 320px it will go back to "normal" and does not work on 320 width devices.

Answer (score 0):

[http://bootply.com/73046](http://bootply.com/73046#)

Think that works, replace the inline height of the div ( it didn't work on me when i put it on the css, so in yours will work on the .css).

Comment: Have you tried to increase height? I saw that at 115px it works on screen too. What's actually your problem?

Comment: I've added an image of the result